# Live streaming using Android

Tags: android, live-streaming

We are trying to develop an app for Android where you can play a live streaming URL. 
I can of course play a static MP4 or MP3 file using the URL (hosted on a server) but I am not sure if we can play a live video content from a stream URL.
Any thoughts?

How should we go about writing the application to play live video content from a url? Kindly help me.

Comment: try to do streaming with rtsp

Comment: if you have a live stream with a url like http://..... m3u8. you can simply use VideoView and give it the url to play. it workds thank

Answer (score 1):

Try below code to implement the Video Streaming from the server you want.
You need to just give the path of the URL.

```
path = "http://www.mediaserveryoururl.com/sample.3gp";
// Create a new media player and set the listeners
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
mMediaPlayer.prepare();
mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Comment: its not works properly give error like Sorry this video cannot be played even if video format Supported by android

Comment: This video won't play, you need to give your server url path from where you want to stream the video.

Comment: (http://www.logisticinfotech.com/MalasiyaCUP/3 Idiots-All Izz Well.mp4) see this until .mp4.its not play

Comment: You can use the VideoView and it play almost every media file and live streams too. thanks